# Why is this assignment not thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I've been reading this book from Joseph Albahari about threading:
http://www.albahari.com/threading/

In Part 2, I found this example:
http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_When_to_Lock

Here is the aforementioned example:

```
class ThreadUnsafe
{
  static int _x;
  static void Increment() { _x++; }
  static void Assign()    { _x = 123; }
}
```

Thread-safe version:

```
class ThreadSafe
{
  static readonly object _locker = new object();
  static int _x;

  static void Increment() { lock (_locker) _x++; }
  static void Assign()    { lock (_locker) _x = 123; }
}
```

I couldn't understand why *Assign* method is not thread safe. Shouldn't integer assignment be atomic operation on both 32- and 64-bit architectures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The assignment is *atomic* in that any reading thread will either see 123 or the previous value - not some intermediate value. However, there's no guarantee that a thread will see the new value until there have been two memory barriers: a write memory barrier in the writing thread, and a read memory barrier in the reading thread.

If you had two threads like this (after making `_x` public or internal, so that it could be read from other types of course - or with the code in the `ThreadSafe` class anyway):

```
// Thread 1
Console.WriteLine("Writing thread starting");
ThreadSafe.Assign();
Console.WriteLine("Writing thread done");


// Thread 2
Console.WriteLine("Reading thread starting");
while (ThreadSafe._x != 123)
{
    // Do nothing
}
Console.WriteLine("Reading thread done");
```

... there's no guarantee that thread 2 would ever finish, because thread 2 might not "see" the assignment from thread 1.

Comment: Could you please explain this while loop? If thread 1 always keeps assigning 123 to _x, what else could Thread 2 read from it?

Comment: @Ivan: What about it? It's just trying to loop until thread 2 "sees" the assignment of 123 to `_x`. The point is that it might never "see" that change.

Comment: I'd expect that eventually the change of one memory location is going to become visible to the other thread as well (after cpu synchronizes memory caches). I don't really understand how can it happen that one thread *never* sees the change although its actively reading from that memory location.

Comment: @Ivan: Suppose the second thread's code copies the value into a register, and then keeps just using that register. That's entirely legal under the .NET memory model.

Comment: Hi @Jon Skeet +1 the concept of memory barrier refers **only** to the fact that the update of a global variable from a particular thread **may** not be visible to the other thread, i.e. one thread may be left with **obsolete (old) values**, right? THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: @Coder23: Well, by "a global variable" - it's *any* variable which can be accessed by multiple threads. But yes, that's the basis of it. (As an aside, please don't shout in comments.)

Comment: hi @Jon Skeet +1 excellent answer, you mean that for a change (update) made by a thread on a global (shared) variable to be visible in other threads there has to be a memory barrier, e.g. a mutex, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer: No, I didn't say that. It *might* be visible in other threads without a barrier, but it's not guaranteed. (And there are plenty of memory barriers other than mutexes, of course - and some will be implicit.)

Comment: hi @Jon Skeet +1, **thanks for replying**, the stale data problem is because the registers keep their **own copies** of the shared variables, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer: Please stop using so much bold all over the place it makes the text much harder to read. There's absolutely *no* reason to put "thanks for replying" in bold, for example - and simple emphasis is more effective with italics. But basically, it's much more complex than *just* registers. Modern memory systems are complex.